# How to Correct the error in this SQL script (Database Using Azure Datawarehouse)

Tags: azure, data-warehouse

I am having a hard time when I try to run the script below.  Error messsage:

> Order by clause not valid in views and inline functions

```
insert into cc.s
(
    id, 
    encid, 
    a_name, 
    a_des, 
    a_type, 
    a_value, 
    d_create
)
select 
    id, 
    encid,
    'days_charge',
    'Days 43',
    'int',
    (
        select 
            datediff(day,t_dis,a.ts_it) 
        from 
            cc.enoun 
        where 
            encid <> a.encid 
            and id=a.pe_id 
            and a_source='tEst' 
            and a.ts_admit > t_dis 
        order by 
            tdischarge desc limit 1
    ) as attr_value,
    getdate()
from 
    cc.s a
GO
```

Comment: what db are you using/ what tool? Try to re-formulate the question in order people not familiar with the context could understand

Comment: I am using Azure Datawarehouse, and also using SSMS tool for editing the query

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you're trying to use a SELECT statement to get the a_value. Your problem here is that this select statement is your inline function. Since an inline function can't have an ORDER BY clause, you simply have to remove it.

```
insert into cc.s(id, encid, a_name, a_des, a_type, a_value, d_create)
select id, encid,'days_charge','Days 43','int',
(select datediff(day,t_dis,a.ts_it) from cc.enoun where encid<>a.encid and id=a.pe_id and a_source='tEst' and a.ts_admit>t_dis)        
as attr_value,
getdate()
from cc.s a
GO
```

Also make sure that your inline statement returns only 1 value. Since you were trying to use an ORDER BY clause, that may mean that it returns multiple results.

Comment: can an inline function return more thEn one value

Comment: No it can't.
Let's say that you have a simple query like this:
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(value1, value2, (SELECT a FROM table_2))
If your inline function (SELECT a FROM table_2) returns multiple values, what do you do? You obviously can't add all of them into one entry in the database.
You can read more here if you want : [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm)